# Override auto generated id in MVC4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()            
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Main.Save" />         
}
```

This is my view model

```
 public class ContentPagePresViewModel
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Contenu de la page
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name = "¨Presentation")]
        [DataType(DataType.Html)]
        [AllowHtml]
        /*[Required(ErrorMessage = "ContentPage_PageContent_Required")]*/

        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want that the id generated for my Description propety don't became "Description".
How I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `UIHint` attribute in combination with a custom editor template.

- From MSDN, regarding UIHint:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx
- This article describes the process in a bit of detail: 
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx

Modify your model to add a `UIHint` attribute:

```
[UIHint("Description")]
public virtual string Description { get; set; }
```

In your specific view's folder, create a new folder called `EditorTemplates`.  Add a new file called Description.cshtml, and add the following content: *(this assumes you're using Razor)*

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBox("", Model, new { id = "_myCustomDescriptionId" })
</div>
```

---

**Here's another idea** to consider.  It might be more straightforward to lay out your fields and editors individually, instead of using `Html.EditorForModel`.  In that case, you can specify html attributes directly like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { id = "_myCustomDescriptionId" });
```